# WordPress Template "X": Change html inside of <head>

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm pretty new to WordPress and want to remove some unneeded js/css files that are loaded inside of the html-head of the page.

In wp-content/themes/x/framework/views/header/base.php I found the following code:

```
<head>
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

This obviously doesn't help me at all. I have no idea what WordPress' "wp_head()"-function does next. Isn't there some simple file where I can just write/edit simple HTML for the "head" somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

`wp_head()` is a function that fires the `wp_head` action hook. Wordpress is built on action hooks and filters, which means that not only can plugins and themes add things to your setup through these hooks, but you have the ability to remove things as well. Most of this is done programmatically (in PHP) instead of there just being an html template, although that's not always the case... but it IS the case in your case.

Scripts and styles, for the most part, are enqueued through the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook. You'll want to perform your script removals here.

The problem is, you'll have to know the name the script was registered as before you can remove it. For instance, jQuery is registered as `'jquery'`. Pretty simple, right? However, not all scripts are going to be that simple, and you'll have to browse through the code to find the registered handles (names) for those scripts. Styles are a bit easier, as when you inspect your page in the browser, styles will have an id attribute set to `'example-style-css'`. Wordpress appends the '-css' to registered and enqueued styles, so the name of your style is actually 'example-style'.

In your theme's functions.php, you can dequeue scripts and styles so they won't be included on your page like so:

```
function stack_46669800_dequeue(){
    wp_dequeue_script('the-script-you-want-to-remove');
    wp_dequeue_style('the-style-you-want-to-remove');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','stack_46669800_dequeue',100);
```

(Notice the 100 in the `add_action` function here... This is the 'priority', or the order in which all added actions are fired. Most are at 10, so I changed the priority here to 100 so this would be fired presumably later than whatever is enqueueing your unwanted scripts. You can't dequeue something that hasn't been enqueued yet.)

Comment: Okay, but wouldn't it be better to prevent them from being queued in the first place, instead of removing them from the queue?

My next problem is, that there are a couple of inline css/js scripts that I want to edit/remove aswell.

Comment: @snmueller89 - If you are following WordPress' recommendations of using a child theme (which you should be!) then you can dequeue the scripts/styles within your child theme, rather than editing/customising the parent theme (which you shouldn't be doing!).

Comment: @snmueller89 "...wouldn't it be better to prevent them..." No, because that's not how Wordpress works. There are many scripts queued by default/Wordpress core, and then plugins can/will queue their own scripts too. All this happens before your theme is loaded.

Comment: @MatthewB is absolutely correct! I just didn't want to get into a whole side discussion of the importance of a child theme because the answer was already getting long. But thank you for that!

Comment: Okay, I can understand that. But how do I find the registered handles? And how can I remove the inline-scripts? Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @snmueller89 that unfortunately is an entirely different question you must pose to the SO community. Please make sure to provide them code that you've tried on your own first.